# How to perform the following complex integration in two variable?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, symbolic, complex

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\mathrm dx\mathrm dy}{xy}\sinh(\pi x)\sinh(\pi y)e^{\pi i(2x^2+y^2)}\sin(\pi x y)$$

Here both integration variables $x$ and $y$ run from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. I have tried the following code, but it is answering zero, which is not the correct answer. An answer is a non-zero number something 0.8, might be a complex number.

[image: my code]

```
Integrate[(Sinh[Pi*x]*Sinh[Pi*y]*Sin[Pi*x*y]*E^(Pi*I*(2*x^2 + y^2)))/
   (x*y), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

Comment: please post plain text Mathematica code as well, so one can copy and paste it. A little hard to copy code from an image.

Comment: Think of NIntegrate[(Sinh[Pi * x]*Sinh[Pi * y]*Sin[Pi * x * y] * E^(Pi * I*(2 * x^2 + y^2)))/(x * y) /. y -> 1, {x, -100, 200}] which results in $ -1.07749\times 10^{265}-2.68302\times 10^{262} i$. This suggests the divergence of the improper double integral under consideration.

Comment: Executing Integrate[(Sinh[Pi * x]*Sinh[Pi * y] * Sin[Pi *x * y]*E^(Pi * I* (2 * x^2 + y^2)))/
   (x * y), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}] in version 12.0, one obtains an error communication "integral of (E^(I \[Pi] (2 x^2+y^2)) Sin[\[Pi] x y] Sinh[\[Pi] x] Sinh[\[Pi] y])/(x y) does not converge on {-\[Infinity],\[Infinity]}" and the returned input.

Comment: Both  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value as well as https://encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Improper_integral say only about multidimensional integrals where the integrand has an isolated singularity at a point. In view of it the integral from the question cannot be treated as its Cauchy principal value. Therefore, 0 because of the oddity of the integrand in x  is a wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution zero is true, since the integrand is anti-symmetric in x and y.

```
integrand[x_, y_] = 
   (Sinh[Pi*x]*Sinh[Pi*y]*Sin[Pi*x*y]*
 E^(Pi*I*(2*x^2 + y^2)))/(x*y);

integrand[x, y] + integrand[-x, y]
```

yields zero.

Comment: We deal with an improper double integral. Its convergence is doubtful in view of NIntegrate[(Sinh[Pi * x]*Sinh[Pi * y]*Sin[Pi * x * y] *
     E^(Pi * I*(2 * x^2 + y^2)))/(x * y) /. y -> 1, {x, -100, 200}] which results in $-1.07749\times 10^{265}-2.68302\times 10^{262} i $.

Comment: Have a look at the integrand with Plot to see,it is increasingly highly oscillatory. Why don't you integrate from `{x, -200, 200}] ` ?

Comment: Look in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral for the definition of an improper integra over $(-\infty,\infty)$. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: Thanks, need no explanation from you. If integrand is anti-symmetric, every integral from -a to a or - inf to inf yields zero.

Comment: -1. No, it is not true. Think of $\int_{-\infty}^\infty x \,dx$ as an example of a divergent improper integral

Comment: Convergence at infinity is not obvious and should be validated in some way.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: If you mean the Cauchy principal value, then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value says only about  multidimensional inegrals where the integrand has an isolated singularity at a point.

Comment: @ user64494  the Wikipedia side you mentioned says `In this case, one can however define an improper integral in the sense of Cauchy principal value:` .  `p.v ...==0 ` .   I mean  en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Improper_integral

Comment: @Akku 14:  But https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value as well as https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Improper_integral say only about multidimensional integrals where the integrand has an isolated singularity at a point. In view of it the integral from the question cannot be treated as its Cauchy principal value. Hope I am clear.

Comment: No, it's not a Cauchy principal value singular integral. The issue is that it is unclear whether the oscillation is sufficiently fast to handle the growth at infinity. A way to check convergence is to get a first-order approximation of the result from one period of oscillation, as a function of either variable. Then check whether summing such terms will converge.

Comment: As an addendum to my comments, I will mention that I am familiar with the convergence testing code in `Integrate`. More than anyone else, in fact. So take this as tacit admission that it is by no means without flaws. This is very much an issue when it comes to assessing oscillatory integrands at infinity.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: You wrote "A way to check convergence is to get a first-order approximation of the result from one period of oscillation, as a function of either variable. Then check whether summing such terms will converge".  Can you explain what you mean by one period of oscillation for a function of two variables? BTW, the result of Table[NIntegrate[(Sinh[Pi * x] * Sinh[Pi*y] * Sin[Pi * x * y] *
      E^(Pi * I * (2 * x^2 + y^2)))/(x * y) /. y -> 1, {x, Pi * n, 
   Pi * n + Pi}], {n, 20, 30}] do not show any convergence.

Comment: @user64494 I mean fix one variable, assess behavior. If convergent then since we know the value is zero, integrating over the second variable is not going to cause trouble.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau:  It seems you don't look at the results of the commands suggested by me. I repeat that results do not show any convergence. Waiting for serious replies of you.

Comment: @user64494 I do not know that it converges. Also your test is not quite right. It requires checking a period of the more rapidly oscillating function-- the periods are not in general commensurate, that is, for arbitrary `y`.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: You wrote" I do not know that it converges". What do you mean by "it"? Can you ground your suggestion  "A way to check convergence is to get a first-order approximation of the result from one period of oscillation, as a function of either variable. Then check whether summing such terms will converge" by a code? I prefer arguments over directions and unconstructive criticism. All the best.

Comment: By it I refer to the integral in question. As for the rest, I pass (We are still working, albeit remotely, and I do have things I need to do. And maybe so do you.)